# Draw circle shape programmatically in android

Tags: java, android, android-custom-view, android-drawable

What I want to do is to draw a circle and fill it by one color (for example orange) and want to make a border in another color (blue) programmatically. I didn't find any tutorial on how to do this.

This is what I want to get:

[image]

Comment: My keyword is : custom drawable shape android

Comment: Please check my updated answer and let me know if that helped. :)

Answer (score 11):

To achieve the circle drawable programmatically you need to have a function like the following.

```
public static GradientDrawable drawCircle(int backgroundColor, int borderColor) {
    GradientDrawable shape = new GradientDrawable();
    shape.setShape(GradientDrawable.OVAL);
    shape.setCornerRadii(new float[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0});
    shape.setColor(backgroundColor);
    shape.setStroke(10, borderColor);
    return shape;
}
```

And set the `drawable` in your `ImageView` like the following.

```
imageView.setBackground(drawCircle(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_blue_dark), getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_dark)));
```

This is giving something like this.

[image]

Comment: thanks but I wanna do it programatically in my java code

Comment: umm ... can you please let me know what is the use-case where you want to do this programmatically?

Comment: So actually I'm gonna have class called Circle and implement drawing of concrete circle

Comment: @AslanAlmaniyazov I think you can create your own class Circle and put this code to it if you need to have your own Circle class.